# Loop over Reducing Matrix Dimensionality, Bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, matrix

My goal is to take a set of vectors, which run over an index i, and reduce their dimensionality by one for every zero in the array. In particular, I have a set of vectors which have elements

```
vecA_$i=[ a 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 b ]
```

and I just want to reindex them to have the vector [ a b ], a 1x2 instead of a needless 1x16. If I have just one vector, I can do

```
VecA_1=("${VecA_1[@]:0}")
```

and this works just fine. However, I am having difficulty doing this over a loop. I attempted to do

```
for (( i=1; i<=$directory; i++ ))
do
VecA_$i=("${VecA_$i[@]:0}")
done
```

but this results in a syntax error on the definition line. Can anyone advise how to perform a do loop over a matrix dimensionality reduction?

Comment: It's not clear how your attempt without the loop works _just fine_, as it looks like you're just taking a slice of the array starting from the 0th element (i.e. a copy).

Comment: Does the assignment to `VecA_$i` work...?

Comment: @TomFenech Is the action not simply to pull non-zero matrix elements?

Comment: `"${vec[@]:0}"` [takes a slice of the array `vec` starting from the 0th element](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). I'm not sure where you got the idea that it would remove the 0s.